# Where can I find WebSphere configuration files?

Tags: configuration, files, websphere

I would like to know where are the WebSphere configuration details saved?

Specifically, configuration details that are shown in the Administrative Console (from the web) or from the console using wsadmin.

Some of the examples would be:

1. Java and Process Management: Class
   loader, Process definition, Process
   execution
2. Container Settings:
   Session management, SIP Container
   Settings, Web Container Settings,
   Portlet Container Settings

Are there XML files that persist these configuration details?

Nicholas

Answer (score 5):

Nicholas,

WebSphere stores all its configuration in XML files. These files are stored within your WebSphere profile. Assuming you installed WebSphere in its default path you should find them here:

Windows:
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles(profile_name)\config\cells(cell_name)

Linux:
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/(profile_name)/config/cells/(cell_name)

Where profile_name is either "default" or "AppSrv01" and cell_name is something like hostnameNode01Cell.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.